# Facebook Login Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Facebook login is not working. I dont know why.

Following is the FB js code :

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
        $(document).trigger('fbStatusChange', response);
    });

    FB.init({
        appId: '419718681491265', // App ID
        channelUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1/9377/', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Following is the App dashboard:

[image: App dashboard]

Please help..Tired of banging my head

The error is :
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't test Facebook connect locally.
So a URL of 127.0.0.1 will not work.

Comment: It was working perfectly earlier about 2 months back.. You might be right though..fb must have changed its api